# Add an application in the i3wm menu

Tags: command-line, firefox, i3-wm

I am unable to find the Firefox Developer Edition Browser in the i3 menu (using +D). I have installed and it works perfectly fine in Ubuntu GNOME, and also through the terminal in i3.
However, how can I make it appear in the i3 menu?
Here is my setup code for fde.desktop in /usr/share/applications:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Favorite;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp; X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognitos;
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
```

P.S.: The same code is present in .local/share/applications/fde.desktop. Can someone explain to me the purpose/significance of the desktop file in both the directories too?

Answer (score 3):

Check you i3 config file:

```
# start dmenu (a program launcher)
bindsym Mod1+d exec dmenu_run
# There also is the (new) i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications
# shipping a .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that
# bindsym Mod1+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop
```

By default it's using `dmenu_run` which will list only programs in user's `$PATH`. If you want it to display applications defined in `.desktop` files you need to use `i3-dmenu-desktop`.